# Spring Injecting Values from Property file - Default Value taking precedence

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations, springfox

I have injected a value from my "application.properties" file. The value for test.scope is configured as "testscope". When I print the value of scope in my program , it is printing as "defaultScope". Value "testscope" (configured in application.properties) is printed for testScope variable where I am not setting any defaults.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("testservice")
public class TestServiceController {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestServiceController.class);

    @Value("${test.scope:defaultScope}")
    private String serviceScope;

    @Value("${test.scope}")
    private String testScope;

    @RequestMapping(value="/postTest", method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<PostTestResponse> postTest( @RequestBody PostTestRequest request) {
        LOG.info(" defaultScope gets printed = " + serviceScope);
        LOG.info(" testscope gets printed = " + testScope);     
        return null;
    }
}
```

My assumption was that "defaultScope" should only get printed if no value for "test.scope" is set in application properties file. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Your assumption is correct.  Are other properties getting injected from your application.properties file?  Perhaps you have a typo somewhere, like applicatoin.properties

Comment: Hi R.C , pasted the example

Comment: What is serviceScope?

Comment: sorry lane.maxwell. typo when pasting here. It am fetching the same property value. But when I give default value , it takes precendence

Comment: I was using SpringFox-Swagger-2.7.0. When I downgraded it to 2.4.0 , @Value is working as expected.

Comment: Show your `application.properties` and the actual output that you get when running the above code.